# Flatten parallel nested window trees

Tags: window, list

Sometimes when moving windows around in emacs, it will get to a state where there is a horizontal or vertical stack of windows which appears to be a single list, but is actually made up of multiple nested window lists.

For example, what appears on the screen is a single horizontal line of windows:
`A B C D`
but what is stored in emacs is
`(A (B C) D)`

Is there a function that will remove this unnecessary nesting? I couldn't figure out any good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use -flatten from the dash library.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work as it combines horizontal and vertical stacks together. Even if it did, it returns the tree instead of setting it, and I don't know that there's a way to directly set the window tree.

Comment: @Prismavoid: `set-window-configuration`.